# Request Form to generate ticket in Jira

Tags: flow, integration, webhooks

Two companies. Both on different domains.

**Requirements:**

- Company A has Sharepoint Online
- Company B has Jira Online
- Company A needs to request resources off of Company B

**High Level Plan:**

- Company A would fill in a Sharepoint form.
- More than likely the user would want to attach small files to the form (Office files)
- **On submitting, this would trigger generating a ticket in the Jira System**
- On the Jira, side this would do the relevant notification for someone to react.
- For the flow coming back the other way, this would likely involve picking up a telephone.

**What is the best approach and technology to use to make this happen?**

I have been doing some reading up on Microsoft Flow and Webhooks, but not sure if I am on the right track.

Also open to alternative suggestions on achieving the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Can Jira accept emails from the list?  You could use SPD workflow to add the info from the SP list and send it to Jira in an email to parse.  That is an idea...

Comment: But would that have the ability to pass across files uploaded into the Form. 
If we assume that Jira could handle an incoming email with attachments, I am not sure if Sharepoint lets you include files uploaded into the email?

Comment: That is where you would have to get custom.  You could write a web part/bridge to it to process that in C#; then you could send attachments.  As long as you can pass through your authentication credentials from SharePoint to Jira, (might be able to use the secure store for that).  I do believe there are SharePoint hooks for Jira.  I do not think you will be able to do this in an online presence though.  The attachments are what will get you. Attachment passing will require a server solution.  The meta data passing should be possible though; even in online.